# Random Walk Problem in real axis

Tags: combinatorics

A frog, at the beginning, sits at the origin of the real axis jumps either to left or right by one unit. Find the number of ways that after 20 jumps it returns back to the origin.

Thanks!

Comment: Hint: To get back to the origin, the frog has taken 10 jumps to the left, and 10 to the right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is $20 \choose 10$.

Basically, we are looking for the number of ways one can write a sequence of twenty $1$'s (right jumps) and $-1$'s such that the sum is equal to zero.
We immediately see that the number of $1$'s must equal the number of $-1$'s, so the problem reduces to the following: count the number of ways in which we can write a sequence of twenty numbers: ten $1$'s and ten $-1$'s. To obtain such a sequence, we only have to choose the positions for $1$'s - that is, from twenty available positions, we must choose ten positions in which we write $1$. The remaining ten positions are then occupied by $-1$'s.
The number of ways in which we can choose $10$ positions out of $20$ is $20 \choose 10$.